# "Error parsing the query" while getting @@Identity from SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm writing a simple desktop application in which I'm using a local SQL database (SQL Server CE).  Here is the problematic section:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\App_Data\\Rosters.sdf");
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Insert into Teams (LeagueID, TeamName, Color) values ({0},'{1}','{2}');SELECT @@IDENTITY;", leagueID, txtTeamName.Text.Replace("'", "''"), txtColor.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
conn.Open();
int teamID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

The problem is that I'm getting an exception when I call `cmd.ExecuteScalar`.

The exception message reads,

> *{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number =
>   1,Token line offset = 97,Token in error = SELECT ]"}*

I have run the exact same command in the exact same database through a direct query, and it runs fine - which makes me think the problem is not with SQL Server CE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks marc.  Unfortunately that doesn't work.  I get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Compact only supports a single statement per command, so first run the insert statement with executenonquery, then get the identity with executescalar, and remember not to close the connection in between

Comment: :-) 7 years later, and [still answering the same common question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8afa446d-1c9d-4378-af02-88a2170b32f4/scopeidentity-sqlce-problem). Don't worry, I know the feeling.

Comment: @Joshua did you try the suggestion? Did it work? Whether it is SQL Server Compact or SqlCeConnection that doesn't support multiple statements in a single batch, does that really matter if the suggestion makes your code work?

Comment: @Joshua what do you mean by direct query? If you mean SSMS or Sql CeToolbox, then those tools split each statement and run each individually